# why do I get a CORS error when I try to pass a cookie to the request headers using axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt, cors, mern

Okay so I am creating a log in page for a website im working on, i used json web token to create a token then i use res.cookie() to send it to the server. At first, i was seeing the cookie in only the response headers and not the request headers, so i searched online and saw that i should add
'axios.defaults.withCredentials = true' , but that gave me a CORS error. i might have set up CORS wrong or something, i would post the necessary code, Please someone should tell me where i got it wrong. i would be happy to post any other code at a request.

LoginPage.js

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const LoginPage = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.post('auth/login',{email,password})
        } catch (error) {
            return error
        }
        
    }

    return(
        <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
            <div className="mb-64">
                <h1 className="text-4xl text-center mb-4">Login</h1>
                <form className="max-w-md mx-auto" onSubmit={(e)=> handleLogin(e)} >
                    <input 
                        type="email" 
                        placeholder="your@email.com"
                        name='email'
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="password" 
                        placeholder="password"
                        name='password' 
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button className="primary">Login</button>
                    <div className="text-center py-2 text-gray-500">
                        Don't have an account yet? <Link className="underline text-black" to={'/register'}>Register now</Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js(front-end)

```
import './App.css';
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import {Layout} from './Components/Layout'
import { Homepage } from './Pages/Homepage';
import { LoginPage } from './Pages/LoginPage';
import { RegisterPage } from './Pages/RegisterPage';
import axios from "axios";


axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

export const App = () => {
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Layout/>}>
        <Route index element={<Homepage/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage/>}/>
        <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterPage/>}/>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

auth.js( authentication controllers on the backend)

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const {StatusCodes} = require('http-status-codes')
const { BadRequestError, UnauthenticatedError } = require('../errors')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const bycryptSalt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
const jwtSecret = 'kjwndoifjhnemdkjenekdmdkmdoeijenmekoiejwmkwojn'

const register = async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body
    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, bycryptSalt)
    })
    res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json(user)
}

const login = async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body

    if(!email || !password){
        throw new BadRequestError('Please provide both email and password')
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({email})

    if(!user){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid credentials')
    }

    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
    if(!isPasswordCorrect){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid credentials')
    }

    jwt.sign({email:user.email, id:user._id}, jwtSecret, {}, (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.cookie('token', token).json('login successfull');
    })

}

module.exports = {
    register, login
}
```

app.js (backend)

```
require('dotenv').config()
require('express-async-errors');
const cors = require('cors')

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const connectDB = require('./db/connect');

//routers
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')

// error handlers
const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middleware/not-found');
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require('./middleware/error-handler');

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({credentials: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//routes
app.use('/auth', authRouter)

//errors
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);


const port = 5000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

Comment: You must set a CORS `origin` when using `credentials: true`. You cannot use `*` which is the default for the `cors()` middleware